# How can I Filter overlapping circle?

Tags: geometry, visualization, distance, preprocessor

[image: Image_before]

I want to leave only the part surrounded by red in the second picture.

I want to leave all circles that overlap with other colors, and erase circles that do not overlap or overlap with the same colors. Since there is so much actual data, I want to write an efficient code.

What can I do?

[image: Image_after]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the radius of each circle is a constant `R`. (If not, arrange the logic below.)

Organize the data as follows.

Make a list of all colors.

Make a dictionary, the keys are the colors in the above list, the value for a specific `color` is the list of the centers of the circles of that color.

Make an empty list `L`, at the end it will contain all needed circles.

We will now loop among colors. Let `color0` be such a color.

Let `(x0, y0)` be the center of a circle of this color. So we are looping among them. If the corresponding circle is already in `L`, everything is fine, go on to the next center in this color, if any. Else inspect if this center survives, and should be added to the list...

For each **other** color `color1`, and for each center `(x1, y1)` in this other color compare the distance between the centers `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` with the common radius `R`, if it is smaller than add boths centers to the list `L` and go to the next point `(x0, y0)`. (If not still search...)

After this search, the list `L` contains the needed centers. (It may be of course better to add to the list objects that record all the data, e.g. color, center, et caetera depending on the needs.)